# Environment set up for Almond Automation

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-grid

Anyone familiar with almond automation. Can give a guide? I cannot execute the test case successfully. There is no result coming out.

Comment: What have you tried?what's the program language you are using now?That's not clear./

Comment: Almond automation is a codeless web functional testing tool based on selenium grid. http://almond-automation.blogspot.com/p/home.html
I install in through docker. I want to use this almond automation to run testing. 
I using this automation tool write test case. But i cannot get the result. I think because of my environment set up wrong.